# SendGrid response status code 0 no further information

Tags: sendgrid, php-7.2, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send a mail using the [SendGrid PHP API library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php). It worked when I tried it yesterday but today the reponse just has zero information:

```
SendGrid\Response Object
(
    [statusCode:protected] => 0
    [body:protected] => 
    [headers:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )
)
```

The following object is being used in the `\SendGrid\SendGrid()->send()` method:

```
SendGrid\Mail\Mail Object
(
    [from:SendGrid\Mail\Mail:private] => SendGrid\Mail\From Object
        (
            [name:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => test1
            [email:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => test@example.com
            [substitutions:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => 
            [subject:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => 
        )

    [subject:SendGrid\Mail\Mail:private] => SendGrid\Mail\Subject Object
        (
            [subject:SendGrid\Mail\Subject:private] => this is a test
        )

    [contents:SendGrid\Mail\Mail:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => SendGrid\Mail\Content Object
                (
                    [type:SendGrid\Mail\Content:private] => text/html
                    [value:SendGrid\Mail\Content:private] =>
<h1>sending mails</h1>
                )

        )

    [attachments:SendGrid\Mail\Mail:private] => 
    [reply_to:SendGrid\Mail\Mail:private] => 
    [personalization:SendGrid\Mail\Mail:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => SendGrid\Mail\Personalization Object
                (
                    [tos:SendGrid\Mail\Personalization:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SendGrid\Mail\To Object
                                (
                                    [name:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => mr test
                                    [email:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => testtest@example.com
                                    [substitutions:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => 
                                    [subject:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [ccs:SendGrid\Mail\Personalization:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SendGrid\Mail\Cc Object
                                (
                                    [name:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => 
                                    [email:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => testtest1@example.com
                                    [substitutions:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => 
                                    [subject:SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [bccs:SendGrid\Mail\Personalization:private] => 
                    [subject:SendGrid\Mail\Personalization:private] => 
                )
        )
)
```

Obviously I used correct addresses in the `tos` and `ccs` sections.
Is something wrong with the sent object?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the code if there are any other problems in sending mail the send-grid library remains silent without throwing any exceptions and just returns the response 0. I would suggest you to
[visit this link](https://github.com/sendgrid/php-http-client/pull/99)

1. In php-http-client\lib create a folder Exception.
2. Copy [lib/Exception/InvalidRequest.php](https://codecov.io/gh/sendgrid/php-http-client/pull/99/diff?src=pr&el=tree#diff-bGliL0V4Y2VwdGlvbi9JbnZhbGlkUmVxdWVzdC5waHA=) into the folder.
3. Modify [lib/Client.php](https://codecov.io/gh/sendgrid/php-http-client/pull/99/diff?src=pr&el=tree#diff-bGliL0NsaWVudC5waHA=)

These modifications are to throw appropriate exceptions which will help you to find what could be the problem in your case and be able to take it further.